# XMLReader.ReadToFollowing Escape Quotes

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I want to use XMLReader to read something from an HTML Code.

I use this Line to jump to the needed Value:

```
reader.ReadToFollowing("type=""hidden"" name=""key"" value");
```

But this throws errors over errors. How can I Escape the quotes in this line?

Comment: Even if you escape the quotes correctly (use backslash instead of doubling the quote), I don't think this is going to work... `ReadToFollowing` takes an element name... not some arbitrary chunk of XML.

Comment: an XMLReader is not the same as a StreamReader. You dont jump to the needed line...it reads all the XML up until that line into your XMLReader

Comment: Side note: please don't add "thank you notes" to your post and tags to title for future questions. Feel free to discuss this recommendation on META starting with [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266525/being-polite-while-asking-a-question/266531#266531).